# Android setWindowLayoutMode not working before SDK 11

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a PopupWindow in Android that centers itself in the middle of the display and is dynamically sized to the content of the loaded view. In addition, any tap outside of the popup should dismiss the popup. In SDK versions 11 on, this code works just fine, however in SDK 10 (the minimum our app must support), the setWindowLayoutMode seemingly does nothing.

I've so far subclassed this logic, which seems clean and efficient to me, with the exception of the issue (bug?) with SDK 10. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? I see that setWindowLayoutMode has been around since version 3, so I'm having trouble believing it is simply not working as it is described to in the documentation. If an SDK bug is the case, how might I workaround the problem? I tried .measure() on the contentView with the screen dimensions as the restrictions with the intention of manually setting the window size, but the values it returned were wildly different from the expected results.

I can easily get the window centered by wrapping the TextView in a layout that I can set to match the screen dimensions, but then I lose the nice ACTION_OUTSIDE tap event, so I'd rather not stumble down that path if I can avoid it.

I should mention that the problem that is happening on SDK 10 is that the window simply doesn't appear... It is technically "appearing", either with dimensions of 0,0 or offscreen, as subsequent taps trigger the OnTouchListener, but it surely is not correctly displaying its contents.

```
public class InfoPopupWindow extends PopupWindow {
    private View _parentView;

    public InfoPopupWindow(Context context, View parentView) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.window_info, null, false);
        this.setContentView(contentView);

        this.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        // This combo of parameters sends outside events properly, and inside events as well.
        this.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        this.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        this.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                    Log.d("InfoPopupWindow", "Outside Window Touch Event");
                    dismiss();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        this.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation);

        _parentView = parentView;
    }

    public void show() {
        this.showAtLocation(_parentView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

**R.layout.window_info**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/info_text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="15dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never found the solution to the broken setWindowLayoutMode, but I was able to call this method from the constructor to get API 10 to correctly size the popup. The workaround was one I had tested before, but I had been misusing the MeasureSpec parameters. Hope this helps someone else out someday...

```
private void calculateAndSetContentViewSize(Context context, View contentView) {
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        Point windowSize = new Point();
        display.getSize(windowSize);
        screenWidth = windowSize.x;
        screenHeight = windowSize.y;
    } else {
        screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        screenHeight = display.getHeight();
    }

    int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(screenWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(screenHeight, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    contentView.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
    this.setWidth(contentView.getMeasuredWidth());
    this.setHeight(contentView.getMeasuredHeight());

    this.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
```